# how to call a js function in html

Tags: javascript, html

enter code hereI have an issue with my html. I am trying to save an input to my localstorage. For some reason, whenever I inspect my website I don't see the word I typed in my field. In other words it is not loading the input to my localstorage.
I am new to html and javascript and I am hoping you guys can help me out. I'm providing a picture to demostrate what I am trying to approach.

[image]

```js
function getInput(){
var nameInput = document.getElementById('inputName').value;
localStorage.setItem('text', dataInput);

var dateInput = document.getElementById( 'inputDate').value;
localStorage.setItem('text1', dateInput);
}
```

```html
  
<form class="form-horizontal">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Endorse me</legend>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">Name</label>
      <div class="col-lg-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputName" placeholder="Name"> 
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">Date</label>
      <div class="col-lg-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputDate" placeholder="Date">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-2">
        <button onCLick="getInput()" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" >Submit</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Have you checked your browser console for errors? Also `.getELementByID()` should be `.getElementById()`

Comment: Yeah, it does not give me any error. I provided a picture.

Comment: Yeah I can use onCLick but that doesn't solve my problem. Whenever I type something in the input field. I should be seeing that in my Local Storage under key.

Comment: submit buttons submit the form and load a new page (which can be the same page but a new one)

Comment: function getInput() {

var JsObject =[];
var nameinfield = document.getElementById('inputName').value;
var dateinfield = document.getElementById('inputDate').value;


if (localStorage.getItem('datastorage')!=undefined) {
 var JsObject = JSON.parse(localStorage.datastorage);

}

JsObject.push({'idname':nameinfield, 'iddate':dateinfield});
localStorage.setItem('datastorage',JSON.stringify(JsObject));
print();

}

Comment: I'm not dealing with buttons right now. Once I input any word it should be display in local storage under 'key.

Comment: @crucl please don't paste source code as a comment. Update/edit your answer to include changes. Thank you.

Comment: how do I edit my answers?

Comment: @crucl By clicking `edit` under your original post... You should see -  `share` **`edit`** `close` `delete` `flag` -  just below your question.

Comment: `localStorage.getItem('datastorage')` will always be undefined.

Comment: Yes, I updated the code in my original post. Do you mind taking at look at it? I used set but it is still not working.

Comment: I figured it out. I needed to call my function inside of my input in my html

Comment: could you help me out with printing my variables onto a table ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46494699/how-to-print-json-object-in-my-table